# Need help modifiying css animation using Javascript(no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following file I am trying to execute, however, I can never get it to work.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Hello</title>
    <style id="1">
        @keyframes anim {
            0% {
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
            }
            25% {
                left: 200px;
                top: 0px;
            }
            50% {
                left: 200px;
                top: 200px;
            }
            75% {
                left: 0px;
                top: 200px;
            }
            100% {
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="box"
        style="animation-duration:6s;color:#FF0000;position:relative;animation-iteration-count: infinite;animation-name:anim"
        onclick="A()">Hello</h1>

    <button type="button" onclick="A()">click</button>

    <script>
      function A() {

        var css = "@keyframes anim {0%   {left:0px; top:0px;}25%  {left:200px; top:" + Math.random() + "px;}50%  {left:200px; top:200px;}75%  {left:0px; top:200px;}100% {left:0px; top:0px;}}"
        document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = css
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and please don't downvote me because I am new to both stack overflow and javascript

Comment: *"Can anyone kindly solve the matter for me."* Which matter?

Comment: You  need to add more details. What do you want to achieve? What would have "worked" for you?

Comment: Math.random() returns a value between 0 and 1. Maybe all you need is a factor. Like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/1tt9dc4n/2/

Comment: kindly explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Didn't downvote because you're new, but downvoted because you are not explaining your self clearly, and looks like you haven't even tried anything. SO is not a **here's my code, fix it** kind of place.

Comment: We should support and teach him not blame. All my stack overflow colleague, i understand what he want to do. Please check out my answer below  & evaluate am i right or not.  It's working in mine.

Answer (score 1):

set variable in css as below:

```
<style> 
  :root {
         --anim-top: 0px;
        }
    @keyframes anim {
            0% {
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
            }
            25% {
                left: 200px;
                top: var(--anim-top);
            }
            50% {
                left: 200px;
                top: 200px;
            }
            75% {
                left: 0px;
                top: 200px;
            }
            100% {
                left: 0px;
                top: 0px;
            }
        }
</style>
```

and change the value of that varible in javascript when you want like below:

```
<script>
     document.body.style.setProperty('--anim-top',Math.random()+'px');
</script>
```

Comment: can you explain more, and why is it document.body, not document.head etc..

Comment: Hi @phenolicdeath   
`<head>` tag is only for syntex and it's content load first on document loading and that writen style apply on document body elements. That's way we should use to `document.body` for change values for css variable and that called less CSS